# keyboard shortcut to preserve un-entered cmd line typing

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard, cmd.exe

You've got most of a command typed out then realize you forgot a step, need to run a different command first. Without touching mouse, in quick edit mode, how not to lose the typing of a command not yet entered? So history is no help.

Comment: Alt+space E K to mark the content you want to copy, then Alt+space E P to paste.

Comment: Bingo, thank you. Feel free to delete the question or answer.

Comment: I always forget to do this, but maybe easier to fudge the exe call in the command so nothing gets done but the text gets into the history. Then up arrow, home key, and a few deletes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit/copy/paste anything in the command line (actually the entire CMD window):

Press Alt+space to see the options.

In this case, press Alt+space E K 
Move the cursor to where you want to start a selection, hold down SHIFT while you move the cursor to the end of the selection.

Press Alt+space E Y (or Alt+space Enter) to copy the selection.

Press Alt+space E P to paste (into the command window) or Ctrl+V to paste into another application.

(Kind of a handy way to get a "screenshot" of a directory listing pasted into another app)

Comment: Works, so I'll mark as correct. Your answer has the advantage of not cluttering up the console, but it's probably easier\quicker to just add a few chars of gibberish to the command, run it, and then call it back from history.

Comment: LOL!  Probably true!  If nothing else, now we have a nice brief tutorial on how to use a rather obscure Windows feature.